# display the values of a JavaScript code in a table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5, symfony-2.3

I have 5 table ('metier', 'tache', 'technicien', 'tarificationtache','intervention')

```
metier ('id','libelle_metier')$ tache('id','libelle_tache','metier_id') 
technicien ('id','actif','user_id') 
tarificationtache('id','tarif','tache_id','technicien_id') 
intervention('id','discription','techbicien_id','tarification_id','client_id'....)
```

to pass an intervention you have to choose first a 'metier'and then a 'tache' to link to this metier then a table that displays the list of technicien with their tarificationtache

I worked this interface with javascript in combobox but I want a solution with php if someone can help me and thank you

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')

@extends('Layouts/master')

@section('content')
<!--  jQuery -->
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">


    var getTachesByMetierUrl = "{{url('/tachesbymetier')}}";
    var getAdresseByClientUrl = "{{url('/adressebyclient')}}";
    var getTarificationsByTacheUrl = "{{url('/tarificationsbytache')}}";
    var getTechniciensByTarificationtacheUrl = " 
  {{url('/techniciensbytarificationtache')}}";



    function getAdresseByClient(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var client_id = val;
            $.get(getAdresseByClientUrl+'/'+client_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.adresses,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
      value="'+item.id+'">'+item.code_postal+'</option>';
                });
                $('#adresses').html(html);

            });
        }
      }
    function getTachesByMetier(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var metier_id = val;
            $.get(getTachesByMetierUrl+'/'+metier_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.taches,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
   value="'+item.id+'">'+item.libelle_tache+'</option>';
                });
                $('#taches').html(html);

            });
        }
    }
    function getTarificationsByTache(val) {

        if(val.length>0) {
            var tache_id = val;
            $.get(getTarificationsByTacheUrl+'/'+tache_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.tarifications,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
  value="'+item.id+'">'+item.tarif+'</option>';
                });
                $('#tarifications').html(html);

            });
        }
    }

    function getTechniciensByTarificationtache(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var tarificationtache_id = val;

   $.get(getTechniciensByTarificationtacheUrl+'/'+tarificationtache_id,
   function (res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.techniciens,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
   value="'+item.id+'">'+item.id+'</option>';
                });
                $('#techniciens').html(html);

            });
        }
    }


</script>



@if(count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
                <li>{{$message}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <h1>Ajout Intervention</h1>
        <form action=" {{url ('intervention')  }}" method="post">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="client">Client</label>
                <select onchange="getAdresseByClient(this.value)" 
 name="client_id" id="client" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    @foreach($client as $t)
                        <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                            {{$t->user->nom}}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">duree_prevu</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local"  name 
 ="duree_prevu" value="{{old('duree_prevu')}}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">description</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="description" class="form- 
control"value="{{old('description')}}">
            </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Metier: </label>
                <select onchange="getTachesByMetier(this.value)" 
 style="width: 200px" class="productm form-control" id="metiers">
               <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    @foreach($metiers as $t)
                        <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                            {{$t->libelle_metier}}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>tache: </label>
                <select onchange="getTarificationsByTache(this.value)" 
 style="width: 200px" class="productname form-control" name="tache" 
 id="taches">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>tarification: </label>
                <select 
 onchange="getTechniciensByTarificationtache(this.value)" style="width: 
 200px" 
  class="productname form-control" name="tarificationtache_id" 
  id="tarifications">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>technicien: </label>
                        <select style="width: 200px" class="productname 
 form-control" name="technicien_id" id="techniciens">
                            <option value="">-Select-</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>



</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="">statut</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="statut" class="form- 
 control"value="{{old('statut')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">payement</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  name ="payement" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form- 
control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"> 
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

@endsection
```

intervention controller

```
  public function create()

{
    $client = client::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $metiers = metier::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $technicien = Technicien::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    $tarifications = tarificationtache::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    return view('intervention.create')->with('technicien', $technicien)- 
>with('client',$client)->with('metiers',$metiers)- 
>with('tarifications',$tarifications);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(InterventionRequest $request)
{
    $intervention = new Intervention();

    $intervention ->description =$request->input('description');
    $intervention ->duree_prevu =$request->input('duree_prevu');
     if($request->has('statut')){
    $intervention->statut = $request->input('statut');
    }else{
           $intervention->statut = 0;
    }

    $intervention ->technicien_id = $request->input('technicien_id');
    $intervention ->client_id = $request->input('client_id');
    $intervention ->tarification_id = $request->input('tarification_id');
    $intervention->save();
    return redirect('intervention');




}
```